# Sitecore Content Hub: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory Error

Tags: content-hub

I have installed Sitecore 10.3.1 and now I am trying to `Install Sitecore Connect for Content Hub on-prem` as mentioned in this document https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/connect-for-ch/51/connect-for-content-hub/install-sitecore-connect-for-content-hub-on-prem.html.

I run this script:

```
<path where you extracted the SCCH SIF installation script>\deploy.ps1 `
-ScchWdpPackage “<path of SCCH module installation package downloaded>” `
-InstanceName “<Sitecore instance name>” `
-InstanceUrl “<Sitecore instance url>” `
-SitecoreAdminUser “<Sitecore admin user name>” `
-SitecoreAdminPass “<Sitecore admin password>” `
-SqlInstanceName “<Sitecore SQL Database prefix name>” `
-SqlUser “<SQL server user name>” `
-SqlPass “<SQL server password>” `
-SqlServerName “<SQL server name>” `
-SkipDatabaseInstallation “<true or false for skip database installation>”
```

But after running this, I am getting below error:

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache..ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCacheOptions>)'.
```

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: It seems dll version changes issues. Did it install or upgrade any dll?
Found this related article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76569045/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found-void-microsoft-extensions-cach

Comment: @GauravAgarwal Thanks for the response. I have not updated any dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its known issue, method not found: `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`

can you please try the following and verify the same:

- Open your Sitecore website folder and navigate to `{sitecore-instance-directory}\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Xdb.ReferenceData.Client`
- rename `Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.ClientCache.config` to `Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.ClientCache.config.disabled`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are currently running your website, I assume locally.

Maybe it helps when looking into the troubleshoot Sitecore refers:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/connect-for-ch/51/connect-for-content-hub/troubleshooting-scch.html#azure-deployment-throws-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftextensionscachingabstractions-error

Underneath that section you also see a few on-premise issue you can look into.

1 last thing just to be sure: you run your script for Sitecore version 10.3.1 there is a note underneath the script:

> If you are deploying SCCH to Sitecore 10.1 and later, you must set the `SkipDatabaseInstallation` parameter to `$true`.

I assume you set this parameter to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you have the compatible version of connector installed from [Sitecore Connect™ for Content Hub compatibility table](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0505663)

Also, to cross check the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions` version with the backup of the web.config before the installation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Shiham for your response. I have checked content hub version is correct as well as Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions dll version is also correct.